# Laravel sync job and specific queue on the same command?

Tags: php, laravel, queue, amazon-sqs

I want to dispatch a new job on a specific queue connection, the thing is that I want it to run right away (sync) on my local machine.

Example:

```
$job = ( new \MyJobClass() )->onConnection('sqs2-connection');
dispatch( $job );
```

How can I make sure this job will run as `sync` on my local env?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
$job = ( new \MyJobClass() )->onConnection( env('QUEUE_CONNECTION_2','sync') );
dispatch( $job );
```